# Where do highlights and marked words go for documents in a Kindle?

Tags: kindle

I have a Kindle Voyage where I put a .mobi document on it. I read this book and highlight few passages and looked for some words on the dictionary.

Due to unexpected latencies and battery leakage, amazon advise me to backup, factory reset and restore my Kindle using the USB Drive. So I did copied the /documents/ folder and factory reset my Kindle.

When I copied my data back to the Kindle, I couldn't see my book, neither my clippings. However the files `My Clippings.txt` and `mybook.mobi` are correctly visible when connected into USB Drive mode.

I resent the book to my amazon email, but I lost the associated highlights and words I looked at.

Where these highlights and words are stored on my Kindle and how it is possible to restore both from my backup? I see plenty of `.sdr` files and maybe they could be the answer I am looking for.